# Symfony cache clear has no effect

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I use

```
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
var_dump($cache->getItem('test_cache_key'));
exit;
```

Now this value is not recorded anywhere. I've tried every possible command:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console cache:pool:prune
php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.app
```

And others like that in a variety of variations.

Also I was clearing /tmp.
And deleted the /var/cache directory in the Symfony project.

But all is useless. When $cache->getItem('test_cache_key') is called, the cache stays in place.

```
object(Symfony\Component\Cache\CacheItem)#2566 (9) {
  ["key":protected]=>
  string(14) "test_cache_key"
  ["value":protected]=>
  string(16) "test_cache_value"
  ["isHit":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["expiry":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["metadata":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["newMetadata":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["innerItem":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["poolHash":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["isTaggable":protected]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I have no idea what to do. Help me please.

UPD.

```
Current configuration for "framework.cache"
===========================================

prefix_seed: _%kernel.project_dir%.%kernel.container_class%
app: cache.adapter.filesystem
system: cache.adapter.system
directory: '%kernel.cache_dir%/pools'
default_redis_provider: 'redis://localhost'
default_memcached_provider: 'memcached://localhost'
default_pdo_provider: database_connection
pools: {  }
```

Comment: Can you show your cache configuration? Preferably the one generated by `php bin/console debug:config framework cache`, not just the yaml config

Comment: Current configuration for "framework.cache"
===========================================

prefix_seed: _%kernel.project_dir%.%kernel.container_class%
app: cache.adapter.filesystem
system: cache.adapter.system
directory: '%kernel.cache_dir%/pools'
default_redis_provider: 'redis://localhost'
default_memcached_provider: 'memcached://localhost'
default_pdo_provider: database_connection
pools: {  }

Comment: formatted in post UPD

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the /var/cache directory usually works (or used to) however
after some reading, I see that some pools can be memcached. This must be your case if it is still present afterwards.

There are at least three different cache clearers: `cache.global_clearer`, `cache.system_clearer`, and `cache.app_clearer`. You have invoked the `cache.system_clearer` with `cache:clear` command and apparently that does not get everything. You need to invoke the `cache.global_clearer`:

> Clear all caches everywhere:
>
> `> php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#clearing-the-cache

Comment: It didn’t work( And I didn't install memcached and redis